# Spring MVC - Autowired Repository NullPointerException in static context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

In my model I have a repository called `UserRepository`. Additionally I have a `UserFacade` that basically adds the user to the repository and is accessed by the Controller. The repo is `@Autowired` in the Facade. When I want to add a new user I get a nullPointerException for the repository.

My `spring-servlet.xml` contains the required

`<jpa:repositories base-package="project.user.repositories" />`

while repositories is the folder containing the `UserRepository.java`. It extends the CrudRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

`Facade.java` is the object containing repository:

```
public class UserFacade {
    @Autowired
    private static UserRepository userRepo;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserFacade.class);

    public UserFacade(){} //Thought it might work if I add a constructor and call it?

    public static User findByUsername(String username) {
        logger.debug(username+userRepo);  // prints SomeStringnull
        return userRepo.findByUsername(username); //NullPointerException
    }
}
```

And from my `controller` I have a method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = CONTEXT)
public String test(){
    User user = UserFacade.findByUsername("get"); 
    //obviously user will be null if there is no such user
    return "success";
}
```

Imports will should not be a problem as I am using Android Studio. What did I miss?

*Note: There are many great answers to related questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)), but each has it's own, different context and didn't help me.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's what I thought too, until I read it (that's why I linked it in my question).

Comment: Right. It's not an exact duplicate but it does give you the solution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis indeed it does give me a lot of valuable information, however I would need a fundamentally different approach (not having static methods), therefore I don't consider it the solution.

Comment: Right and the last part of the answer there shows how to do it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok, in a way it does, but around five corners (hard to grasp..).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring doesn't autowire `static` fields. That is why `userRepo` field is `null`. One way is to make the `UserFacade` a bean itself, and then you can make `userRepo` a non-static field. I would prefer this way. `UserFacade` shouldn't really be a utility class, since it is interacting with the repository bean. It would make much more sense to make it a bean.

Another option is to provide a setter, and use `@Autowired` on that:

```
@Autowired
public void setUserRepo(UserRepository userRepo) {
    UserFacade.userRepo = userRepo;
}
```

Or using it even on a parameterized constructor would work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Is there any way to keep it static (as an alternative to `@Autowired`)?

Comment: @Patrick I guess I gave you two. `setter` and `constructor`. But really you should change it to bean.

Comment: Ups you're right.. I was confused, I thought I couldn't set the static variable variable from a non-static method (while it's the other way round). How would I call the setter? You still recommend to use a bean, why so? I think it doesn't make sense in that context, it's more of a helper class.

Comment: @Patrick It's not a helper class. It's more like a Service class, which interacts with Repository class. And you don't need to call the setter. Spring will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks. I am not really familiar with beans and thought of it more like an entity. But [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) corrects me.
Didn't know of @Autowired on setters, this helped me:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Comment: As I understand, spring needs a default constructor with no parameters, so how would a paremeterized constructor work? The autowired setter is not called, what could be the reason for it?
I have annotated UserFacade with `
@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")` but it doesn't work either if I remove it or only remove @Scope. When should the setter be called? I really have a though time with that^^