# Unable to findAll in Spring, getting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, repository

I am trying to print info about every user in my Mysql DB.
I use function findAll() in Repository interface, but I am getting Null Pointer Exception.

Here is my Repository interface:

```
@Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findOneByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
@GetMapping("/admin/allUsers")
    public String getAllUsers(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("users",this.userRepository.findAll());
    return "admin/allUsers";
}
```

I am getting Null Pointer Exception at the row where excecute model.addAtribute(...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: how you have initialized `userRepository` in your `Controller`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to Autowire `userRepository` or make it a bean itself on the config class. After that, make sure is not a static field. I believe Spring does not autowire static fields.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764164/spring-mvc-autowired-repository-nullpointerexception-in-static-context).

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
```